# How to get the momentum term in a neural network in optim

Tags: machine-learning, lua, neural-network, torch, torchnet

|I have a neural network in torch7 and would like to check how the momentum of the neural network is developing, this because I want to modify/reduce it because I want to do some extra processing with the values and need the velocity term in order to do that. 
So I have something like the following code:

```
for t = 1, params.num_iterations do
  local x, losses = optim.adam(feval, img, optim_state)
        img=postProccess(img,content_imageprep,params)
        print(velocity) -- how?
end
```

And would like to see what the velocity is doing. Anybody know how to do this?

Printing the `optim_state` gives me the following output

```
  v : CudaTensor - size: 1327104
  m : CudaTensor - size: 1327104
  learningRate : 10
  denom : CudaTensor - size: 1327104
  t : 4
```

but I'm now sure if and if so what term represents the velocity, anybody know?

Comment: What is velocity in a neural network? I have never heard of that term before... could you explain?

Comment: @ThomasW When a weight is updated in the same direction repeatedly the update can be larger and larger so as to more quickly converge, if on the other hand a weight is constantly switching between increasing and decreasing then the size of the update can be decreased in order to get closer to the correct value

Comment: Edit: I just noticed that velocity = momentum

Answer (score 1):

You won't find the value of the momentum in the `state` argument but in the `config` argument (which is absent in your function call, then the momentum value will be equal to its default value, i.e 0.9 for `beta1` and 0.999 for `beta2`.

Have a look at the source code https://github.com/torch/optim/blob/master/adam.lua#L24

Comment: Sounds good but what I'm interested in is the actual momentum values of each weight (to see what they are and if they are indeed moving to infinity as I suspect). Do you know how to do this?